# Combine Multiple Lists into Unique String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I have a few lists in columns A, B, and C.
In column D I'm trying to get all possible combinations of outputs from A, B, and C with a formula or VBA, but so far haven't been able to crack it.

I'm trying to achieve this

[image: Example of desired outcome]

Outside of doing it manually, I can't come up with how to make it happen.

Comment: You'll need VBA for this I think. Have you tried using some `For..Next` to combine them?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can remove your headers first, here is a formula you can put in cell D1 and drag down till no more values appear:

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),INDEX(A:A,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(A:A))+1)&" "&INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/COUNTA(A:A)),COUNTA(B:B))+1)&" "&INDEX(C:C,INT((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)))+1),"")
```

And as mentioned in comment, you could also look into VBA.